# Imperativo plural en dialectos con voseo

Tags: subjuntivo, imperativo, voseo, bolivia

Aprendiendo del voseo me acabo de acordar de una situación bastante extraña que ocurrió mientras viajaba por Bolivia:

Andábamos por el medio de la nada en una zona súper rural de Bolivia con una amiga cuando de repente empezó a llover y pasamos por un pueblito chiquitito, donde había una mujer gritando "venín! venín!", queriendo decir que fuéramos a su casa para no mojarnos.

Y sí, dijo "venín" en vez de "vengan". Por si no lo malrecuerde, quisiera saber si alguien sabe de áreas en los que se considere correcta esa forma del imperativo plural? Sé que por lo menos en el español rioplatense se dice "vení" en singular, pero que yo sepa el plural se queda con el "vengan" del ustedeo.

Quizá sea "venid" lo que ha dicho, igual me parece raro ya que el *vosotros* no se usa en Latinoamérica que yo sepa.

También puede ser que por falta de educación crea que a través de añadirle una -n a una forma verbal esa se vuelve plural, como por una analogía espuria al caso de *viene → vienen, venga → vengan* etc.

Qué opinan ustedes? Un errorcito no más, sea por su parte o por la mía? O puede que realmente haya donde se dice así? Repito que se trata del sur de Bolivia.

Saludos desde Alemania,

Konstantin

Comment: Sin descartar la idea de un voseo plural moderno en absoluto (idea que me parece interesantísima), veo dos otras posibilidades: (1) un diminutivo de tipo *-ín* o *-ingo* aplicado al imperativo singular, cosa que no es común pero tampoco desconocida, y (2) teniendo en cuenta las vocales nasales del guaraní, una nasalización de la última vocal que para los hablantes de idiomas como el castellano, alemán o inglés puede parecer la vocal seguida por /n/. Quizás el inventario vocálico reducido del aymará o del quecha tenga algo que ver, aunque lo dudo.

Comment: Pero tengo poquísima experiencia con el castellano boliviano, así que solo son adivinanzas sin grandes fundamentos.

Comment: La explicación de las vocales nasales me parece plausible. Quizá solo me ha visto a mí, dijo "vení" y lo pronunció de una manera tan nasal que me soñó como si hubiera habido una n más. No sé si habrá bolivianos aquí en este foro, tal vez alguien sabe más. Si no, lo que supusiste tú será lo más probable.

Comment: En el sur rural de Bolivia difícilmente haya influencia guaraní. Ni en quechua ni en aymara hay vocales nasales. Quizá haya algún sufijo imperativo con un componente nasal en alguna de ellas. Por lo que rápidamente he podido buscar, el imperativo singular en aymara termina en *-m* y el plural en *-pan*, pero esto es totalmente especulativo.

Comment: *vengan* no es del tuteo, sino que corresponde a *ustedes*

Answer (score 3):

El año pasado estuve en Bolivia de visita a un amigo que trabaja allí desde hace 6 años. Le he preguntado a él porque tiene más experiencia que yo y me ha confirmado lo siguiente.

En la zona de Santa Cruz de la Sierra (que es donde él trabaja) se utiliza "vení" como indicativo del plural de forma generalizadas. Mi amigo afirma que en algunas personas dicen "venín" (o lo parece) como imperativo del plural.

Aunque no es generalizado pero si "personalizado" es decir, los que dicen "venín" siempre lo utilizan así y los que dicen "vení" no añaden la "n".

Answer (score -1):

Lo más probable es que sea por la manera de hablar de la gente en las comunidades rurales, ya que entre ellos es muy común decir "estabanos, andabanos" cuando en realidad quieren decir "estábamos, andábamos", esto pasa muy seguido en México con toda la gente que viene de ranchos, ya que por alguna extraña razón así es su acento. Tengo una amiga que nació en Bolivia, si gustas mañana mismo puedo preguntarle si es que en realidad esa es una forma correcta de conjugar el verbo "ir". Un saludo!